# Database Schema for Storing C++ Classes

Tags: database, database-design, graph-databases

I'm trying to come up with a way of storing the underlying structure of C++ classes in a database, and trying to determine what the best type of database would be/how to lay out information in that database.

C++ classes by themselves as code would be parsed into an AST, which would suggest a tree as a possibile data structure, which would fit well into a graph database. However, I don't think the data could be stored purely as a tree, once you consider that pointers could create a loop. The thought then would be a graph. Being someone primarily familiar with relational databases, I'm not sure what the plausibility of that is. The primary pieces of data that would be needed for a class are:

- Class name
- Children nodes, including their type and offset within the struct

For children nodes that aren't a primitive type, they would have a relationship to the class. This by itself seems like it would fit well inside of a graph database. The main thing I'm having a hard time envisioning is how things like pointers or arrays would be stored. Would those just have different attributes on the edge between the two classes? Is there some other way of storing this data that I'm missing which would work better?

Comment: Saw this https://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/,, but I have never used it, so I do not know how good it is (or not).

Comment: @Nic3500 I found that too, but I don't think it's quite what I'm going for. That is intended for storing C++ objects persistently in a database, whereas what I'm looking to do is store metadata about the structure of the class itself. E.g., for  `std::vector<int*>`, I'd like to store that `my_first` is an `int**` at offset 0, `my_last` is an `int**` at offset 8 (assuming 64-bit), and `my_end` is an `int**` at offset 0x10